# Format of Temperature data from University of Delaware

Tags: r, climate, weather

I am downloading Temperature data from University of Delaware ([http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/download.html](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/%7Eclimate/html_pages/download.html)). In it data which I am downloading is under the following head: "Terrestrial Air Temperature: 1900-2017 Gridded Monthly Time Series (V 5.01)".

But the downloaded data is in format which I don't understand what is that. Just to give you an example, one of the available file is the following format: "air_temp.1901".
Could someone please tell me how can what is this format and how can i open this in R.

Comment: Does the manual page help http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/Global2017/README.GlobalTsT2017.html?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed-width format file, where each field takes a set number of characters. You can read this with `read.fwf` from base R, or `fread` from the `data.table` package.

All the field widths are 8 characters so you can use `read.fwf` and pass sufficient repetitions of 8 to get the data in:

```
> air1900 = read.fwf("./air_temp.1900",widths=rep(8,15))
> head(air1900)
       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6   V7   V8  V9 V10  V11   V12   V13
1 -179.75 71.25 -26.8 -19.0 -22.5 -22.2 -7.8 -0.7 2.6 0.4 -2.7  -8.9 -12.1
2 -179.75 68.75 -29.1 -21.3 -24.5 -24.4 -8.0  0.0 4.0 0.9 -2.8 -10.9 -13.7
3 -179.75 68.25 -29.6 -22.0 -25.2 -25.3 -8.6  0.1 4.4 1.1 -3.3 -11.7 -14.7
4 -179.75 67.75 -28.2 -20.8 -24.3 -24.2 -7.3  2.6 7.5 3.7 -2.0 -11.2 -14.3
[etc]
```

You can then set the column names. The README file explains the first two columns are location and the next 12 are the monthly measurements, but there's also another column at the end that (from a couple of example calculations) seems to be the average of the monthly values:

```
> names(air1900) = c("long","lat",month.abb,"mean")
> air1900[1:5,]
     long   lat   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr  May  Jun Jul Aug  Sep   Oct   Nov
1 -179.75 71.25 -26.8 -19.0 -22.5 -22.2 -7.8 -0.7 2.6 0.4 -2.7  -8.9 -12.1
2 -179.75 68.75 -29.1 -21.3 -24.5 -24.4 -8.0  0.0 4.0 0.9 -2.8 -10.9 -13.7
3 -179.75 68.25 -29.6 -22.0 -25.2 -25.3 -8.6  0.1 4.4 1.1 -3.3 -11.7 -14.7
4 -179.75 67.75 -28.2 -20.8 -24.3 -24.2 -7.3  2.6 7.5 3.7 -2.0 -11.2 -14.3
5 -179.75 67.25 -30.2 -23.3 -26.8 -26.6 -9.0  2.2 7.6 3.2 -3.8 -14.3 -17.4
    Dec  mean
1 -23.6 -11.9
2 -26.8 -13.1
3 -27.8 -13.6
4 -27.2 -12.1
5 -30.4 -14.1
```

You should really wrap this up in a function:

```
read_udel = function(p){
  d = read.fwf(p, widths=rep(8,15))
  names(d) = c("long","lat",month.abb,"mean")
  return(d)
}
```

and then you can do

```
> air1911 = read_udel("./air_temp.1911")
> summary(air1911)
      long              lat              Jan               Feb         
 Min.   :-179.75   Min.   :-89.75   Min.   :-59.000   Min.   :-57.400  
 1st Qu.: -62.25   1st Qu.:-71.75   1st Qu.:-26.800   1st Qu.:-28.000  
 Median :  28.25   Median : 19.25   Median :-13.700   Median :-15.200  
 Mean   :  18.44   Mean   :  1.06   Mean   : -8.377   Mean   : -9.337  
 3rd Qu.:  93.75   3rd Qu.: 52.25   3rd Qu.: 13.700   3rd Qu.: 14.600  
 Max.   : 179.75   Max.   : 83.25   Max.   : 35.300   Max.   : 34.000  
[etc]
```

Just to check I've got this all the right way round, a quick plot with some scaled "August" values:

```
> plot(air1900$long, air1900$lat,col=(air1900$Aug+72)/10)
```

[image]

Not going to win any awards but it shows the data has been read in okay. You can now reformat that however you need, or loop over all the years to read each file and build a bigger dataset etc. But this is the basics.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: "You can now reformat that however you need, or loop over all the years to read each file and build a bigger dataset "  Since files are  ending with .1901,.1902 etc. how can i loop over other files? and related to that how can then merge to make it bigger data file?

Comment: I used following lines as code @Spacedman:                                                                                                                               p<- list.files(pattern = "air_temp.*") ;

read_udel = function(p){
  d = read.fwf(p, widths=rep(8,15))
  names(d) = c("long","lat",month.abb,"mean")
  return(d)
};

#Make a list of that contains all data
read.all <- lapply(p, read_udel)

Comment: To merge dataframe rows you use `cbind`, and your `lapply` code loop looks okay, but these are basic R coding operations so if you are having problems with them do the usual searches for help and then ask another question.

Comment: To add a column to a data frame create a new named column: eg: `d$year = 2001`. To get the year from the file name maybe use `substr` to get a substring of a text string. See the help for `substr` for precise details.