# looping on fixed-width format file and changing them to NetCDF format

Tags: raster, r, netcdf, climate, weather

I have fixed-width format file of temperature data provided by University of Delaware.

For more information on the files, including links to download and the function to read them see: [Format of Temperature data from University of Delaware](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/455783/format-of-temperature-data-from-university-of-delaware)

Since data is given for different years, I have to read and merge them together. I tried doing that with the following lines of command:

```
p = list.files(pattern = "air_temp.*")

read_udel = function(p){
  d = read.fwf(p, widths=rep(8,15))  
  names(d) = c("long","lat",month.abb,"mean")
  return(d)
 }
 
# Make a list of that contains all data:

read.all <- lapply(p, read_udel)
```

But it did not work.

Could anyone of please help me with these.

Comment: You need to explain what "did not work" means. Was there an error message? Was the result not as expected? Also, you should probably delete the followup stuff about converting to netcdf and cropping to the USA, since this will get your question closed for having multiple problems. Format changes and cropping data are separate questions which you should be able to find answers for.

Comment: Also its okay to refer to previous questions that help with this one.

Comment: ok thanks for pointing that out @Spacedman. I am new to this platform but will remember this in future.